# How to read .rst files with Latex?

Tags: latex, javadoc

I'm using javasphinx to generate a javadoc and it works, it generates the .rst files. I would like to create a PDF about these files, but I do not know how to import them into a .tex document to edit it.

```
javasphinx-apidoc -f -o . ../../src/main/java/
```

Comment: Looks like reST is markdown and so cannot be processed by LaTeX. If you want to work with .tex documents you need to use the appropriate options for LaTeX output.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `.rst` file and how you want to work with it?

Comment: Finally I decided to use the .rst files to use them in a sphinx project for conversion to HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to use the .rst files to use them in a sphinx project for conversion to HTML http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html